# How to bind an automatically-set parameter in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

So here's the situation:
I have a label (custom control derviative of it, if it matters), and I need to get its width and height with MVVM. However, if I set either of the parameters to {Binding XXX}, they are no long Auto and thus when I change the font in runtime their size doesn't update.

I read about using ActualWidth/Height, which sounds like just what I need besides the fact that it's not a dependence parameter, thus it seemss like I'd need to break MVVM for it.

Are there any better solutions?

***EDIT***

Well, the element in XAML looks nothing special. Just a million of bindings.

```
<local:DraggableLabel 
                    Content="123" 
                    Margin="{Binding Label2Position, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    FontFamily="{Binding Label2Font.Family}" 
                    FontSize="{Binding Label2Font.Size}" 
                    FontWeight="{Binding Label2Font.Weight}" 
                    FontStyle="{Binding Label2Font.Style}" 
                    Foreground="{Binding Path=Label2Color, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}
                           }"/>
```

The default is,

```
Width="Auto"
```

which doesn't have to be written explicits, but can (changes nothing). It makes it resize when the font changes. If I set it to

```
Width="Binding {Label1Width}"
```

The binding works fine, but I no longer get the auto-adjustment.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Added. No revelations, though. I can post the custom control code as well, but it doesn't mess with this at all, and since it derives from Label should behave the same.

Comment: Is the `Label` width also set to `Auto`?

Comment: Both Width and Height are set to Auto via the properties panel, it's not expressed in XAML but I tested and setting them to Auto in XAML does the same thing.

Comment: Since the `ActualWidhth` property is the binding _source_  it doesn't have to be a `DependencyProperty`. You should use this. Also is `Label1Width` a custom `DependencyProperty` of type `double`?

Comment: How do I bind to it though? It doesn't show up in XAML.
Label1Width is a double proerty in the view class, which invokes the property changed event.

Comment: The default value for `double` is _0.0_. So if you didn't changed it, the value of the binding source can't be `Auto`. Make sure the default value is set to `double.NaN`, which is the value that is expressed the `Auto` string value. It appears that `Label1Width` is defined in your view model?

Comment: Yeah, just read up on Auto being double.NaN. It is defined in the viewmodel indeed. However, if it is set to NaN, then it stays that way, thus trying to get it just gives me NaN.

Then, what I need is a way to somehow get the ActualWidth in the view model.

Comment: If you use MVVM, then the dimension or any other view related attributes don't belong to the view model. Only business data. Why  do you set the width there? Are you telling me `double.NaN` doesn't work?

Comment: No, you got my point wrong. I have no intention to set the width from somewhere in the back (thus no breaking of MVVM), width is one of the inputs to the back logic.
`double.NaN` works for what it's supposed to do, but I need the actual width of the element to calculate things.

Comment: Also `ActualWidth` is a property of `FrameworkElement`. Only controls have it since they derive from this class. It doesn't make no sense to have a width property in your view model. _"width is one of the inputs to the back logic"_, sorry but wha do you mean, user input? If not it doesn't belong there. Why should it? Is it possible that you override the `double.NaN` value, which should be the initial value for `Label1Width`? Maybe you should show the relevant view model part. And why do you think `double.NaN` is not working?

Comment: Again, `double.NaN` works perfectly - it makes the label resize if I bind the width to the property set that `double.NaN`.

Let me give you the context:
I am making a program to mass create PDF certificates. For this, I make a preview of the no-info PDF and display it in an Image, and then have 2 of these labels over the image. The user can drag them into place (thus why they are draggable), and then their position and SIZE are used to calculate where to draw the text in PDF. Thus also why Margin is bound to smth - not to change the Margin, but to get it's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found a workaround.

Since I had create a custom control, I was able to create a new `DependencyProperty` called RealWidth, then I added a OnSizeChanged event that updates it with the value of ActualWidth that you CAN get from inside the element every time the size of the element changes.